# How to list all alements by CAML to SPGridView

Tags: development, caml-query, spquery, spgridview

Is it possible to display the listitems retrieved from a CAML query in a SPGridView?

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but you will need to implement sorting, filtering and paging yourself.

[This CodePlex project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16/sourcecode?fileId=41963&pathId=252438598) includes som basic examples.

The key is that an SPQuery called on a list by

```
list.getItems(yourSPQuery)
```

[(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ms457534.aspx) will return list items that you can use to populate a DataTable or other datasource for the SPGridView